# How can I add "Like" functionality to my blog post without logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Assume I have a blog and some posts made in Rails.
Is there anyway to add "Like" functionality to my blog post so users could Like my posts without logging in? (There is no logging in for users!)

If yes then how can I prevent a single users to like a post multiple times?

I've taught about using sessions to identify the user from past but what is they delete their sessions?

Comment: What actually makes any visitor to your blog post unique?  What makes any internet user unique?  HTTP is stateless- every user is, without a session and browser cookies, identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a complex issue. As you said, you can store this information in a session (so in the cookie), but it is not enough. Simple clearing up the cookie unlocks possibility to vote again. So, my idea is to store the possible information we can get:

- IP address
- User-Agent
- X-Forwarded-For (information about the proxy)

and everything else exists in the http header, like:

- Via (information about the proxy)
- Accept-Language
- Accept-Charset
- Connection

Then store the information that this has been voted in a cookie *and* local browser storage DB.

When someone without cookie and local browser storage wants to vote, try to search for the IP and User-Agent. If you find it, that means this session is suspicious. But you are never 100% sure, the same User-Agents may go from the same IP adress (in case of NAT). So I suggest not to drop such vote, just mark it as *suspicious*, for future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use IP address. Every like should have an IP Address column. You will then need to validate uniqueness of IP per post.

Comment: IP is not unique in the modern networks. When your network is under the NAT, all outgoing IP are the same...